# jQuery UI - Drag and drop sorting and revert

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Please find this jsfiddle I've created [drag n drop no sorting](http://jsfiddle.net/xK76y/1/)

The problem here is that when I put the box from drag-gable area to "drop here" area, the boxes won't be sorted out. For example If I put box2 on "drop here" area, there should not be space remain between box1 and box3. And when I put box2 back to drag-able are it should in between box1 and box3.

I've tried to sort out in `drop` event of draggable area.

The second problem is the box must revert back to the draggable area only if it dropped other than "drop here" area. But here it works partially. If I drag a box from "drop here" area and put outside it, it reverts back to "drop here" area. I want it to go back to drag-able area.

Here is my code:

```
$(function(){

  //$("#eventlist").sortable({connectWith: "#timeline"});
  //$("#timeline").sortable({connectWith: "#eventlist"});

  $(".ui-draggable").draggable({ 
      cursor: "move", cursorAt: { top: -5, left: -5 },
      //snap: " #eventlist", snapMode: "inner"
      revert: "true"      
  });

  $("#eventlist").droppable({
      accept: ".ui-draggable",      
      tolerance: 'fit',
      drop:function(event, ui){
        $("#eventlist").sortable()  ;
      }
  });

  $("#timeline").droppable({
      accept: ".ui-draggable",      
      tolerance: 'fit',      
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        console.log(':::dropped on timeline:::');        
      },
      out: function( event, ui ) {
        $(".ui-draggable").draggable('option','revert','invalid');        
      }
  });
  });
```

How do I sort the boxes when it comes back to drag-able area ??? and how the box revert back to its original (the initial) position ???

Comment: I did something similar a little while ago. You need to be using `sortable` instead of `draggable`. Check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ULmrD/5/ its not exactly your situation but it involves a sortable list dragged to other drop zones, which are actually just other sortable lists it is connected with.

Comment: [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/xK76y/4/) ??? Still it's now working.

Comment: no, not at all. 1) you are still using `draggable`. 2) you are not using `sortable`. 3)you have not used `connectWith`

Comment: I tried with `sortable` and `connectWith`. The problem in my case is that there are not 2 lists. **Drop here** area is `div`.

Comment: OK. If you want the drop area to remain sorted, I think you need to just make it a list instead of a div

Comment: There are 2 parts: list of boxes and `div` where boxes are placed. When box is dragged from list to `div`, the list should be sorted. And when box is dragged from `div` to list, again the list should be sorted according to its sorting order.

Comment: In a real application the boxes will be placed on an image of a timeline. So I can't make it a list.

Comment: Hmm. I think with the proper CSS formatting you could still make it a list. Another possiblity would be to create several dropzones, one for each place on the timeline. I'd have to see some more code or a demo to say anything for sure though

Comment: [sorting but no dropping](http://jsfiddle.net/xK76y/22/). Here sorting works but I can't drop elements.

Comment: I made some edits to your fiddle. is that what you are going for?
http://jsfiddle.net/a63E7/

Comment: Thanks @chiliNUT. Actually I don't want sorting on timeline (droppable area). There should be a sorting only on list of boxes area.

Comment: Please find this fiddle(http://jsfiddle.net/a63E7/6/). In this fiddle sorting works when I drag a box from box list but it does not work when box comes back from droppable to box list. Also throws error `Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on draggable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'option'`.

Comment: Any update for the above commented issue ???

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/a63E7/49/](http://jsfiddle.net/a63E7/49/)

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/kB8Lj/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/kB8Lj/3/). How do I make an element to drop anywhere in drop area ???

Answer (score 0):

Please find this solution: [sorting at one side only](http://jsfiddle.net/kB8Lj/1/)

Still there is a problem. When I drop an element, I goes to the start of the drop area if it's empty. I am not able to drop it anywhere in the area.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#eventList, #timeLine').sortable({
        connectWith: '.initBox',        
        //Whenever Dropped Item
        receive: function (event, ui) {

       if ($(this).attr('id') != 'timeLine') {            
        $(this).find('div.boxes').sort(sortAlpha).appendTo(this);  
            if ($(this).children().length > 5) {
                if ($(this).attr('id') == 'timeLine') {
                    $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
                }
            }
        }
        }
    });

    function sortAlpha(a,b){  
        return a.id.toLowerCase() > b.id.toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1;  
    }

});
```

How do I make it to drop anywhere in drop area ?????

Answer (score 0):

check this http://jsfiddle.net/kB8Lj/57/

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {


$(function() {

$( ".boxes" ).draggable({ revert: true });
$( "#eventList, #timeLine" ).droppable({
accept: ".boxes",
activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
drop: function( event, ui ) {

$item=ui.draggable;$item.css({top:0,left:0});
$(this).append($item);

seen=[]; 

$(this).find('.boxes').each(function(index,item)
{
seen.push($(item).attr('id'));
})

seen.sort();


for(var i = 0 ; i < seen.length ; i++)    
$(this).append($(this).find('#'+seen[i]));



}
});
});

});
```

Comment: sorting at one side works but when I drop a box in drop area it goes to the start of an area. I want it to be place at where user actually dropped it. It should not be dropped at the starting of a drop area.@akbar ali

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20680442/javascript-store-large-range-of-numbers-in-array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20680442/javascript-store-large-range-of-numbers-in-array) do you have a solution for this ???- @akbar ali

Comment: boxes should be dropped anywhere in a gray colored area. Not in a wrapper. I hope you will find some solution.-@akbar ali