# javascript - store large range of numbers in array

Tags: javascript

Please find below the code:

```
var range = new Array();
var start = -15e9;
var end = 15e9;
for(var i=start; i<end; i++){
    range.push(i);
}
```

When I run this code in jsfiddle or in a browser, it gets crashed.
Here the requirement is to store the range of -15x10^9 to 15x10^9.

What is the best way (performance-wise) to store such a large range in javascript ?????

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  Think of the amount of memory you are trying to allocate in one go - this is why it is crashing. If you can expand on the why behind this requirement, we may be able to help.

Comment: What do you need to store that range for? Maybe whoever told you this meant `range = {start: -15e9, end:15e9}`?

Comment: Memory amount 30*10^9 * 8 bytes... 2.4*10^11 bytes.  This is quite a lot for a web page :)

Comment: Ok. I am going to build a timeline with this range using div of 900px. So when user zoom in the div, she can view numbers in between the range. Anyhow I've to accommodate this range is the main requirement.-@Paddy

Comment: How about you then calculate a new, appropriate range whenever the user zooms.

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/YHuSU/](http://jsfiddle.net/YHuSU/). This is very basic thing I've done. How do I calculate and display new numbers when user zooms ???-@reto and @Bergi

Comment: @user3108072: Yeah, do exactly that - calculate them *when the user zooms*. But what do they represent? If they're just the scale, then you don't need to store them anywhere.

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/YHuSU/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/YHuSU/1/). Here I am just changing the width when user zooms and it works. Yes it's a scale only for viewing purpose so user can drop an event on a particular date. How do I show numbers in between the range and display when user zooms ???- @Bergi

Comment: Any guideline for the above commented question ???- @Bergi

Answer (score 1):

You have to ask yourself what kind of operations you need for your range. If for example you only want to check if a number is in the range you can do something like:

```
function range(lo, hi) {
  return function(number) {
    return (number >= lo) && (number <= hi);
  }
}

var r1 = range(-15e9, 15e9);
r1(0); // true
```